# Determine which JavaScript file applied a style?

Tags: javascript, css

We have a complex RIA. A particular element has a rougue "display:none" attached to it, there is no matching CSS file when viewed in the browser inspector - so assuming a JS file somewhere is applying it dynamically. Is it possible to find out which script added it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to debug the js step by step, chrome has a function for that

Comment: Comment scripts until it stops being applied - the last commented script is the suspect. (if not too many scripts of course)

Comment: try using a search for the id perhaps? or check the event handlers?

Comment: Grep over the Javascript files?

Comment: maybe include a link or something so we could try to help?

Answer (score 8):

1. Use Firefox and Firebug.
2. Find the element in the Firebug DOM inspector.
3. Right click on it
4. Pick "Break on attribute change"

or

1. Use Chrome
2. Find the element in the Chrome Developer tools DOM inspector
3. Right click on it
4. Pick Break On… ➡ Attributes Modifications

That will act as if you have a break point at any point in your JS that you have code that changes the attribute. Since `element.style.display = "none"` gets mapped onto the `style` attribute, it will trigger for this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — I only found out about that feature yesterday :)

Comment: Oh that's a new one, well useful!

Comment: I'd replace the step 1 with "use Chrome" ;-)

Comment: Pretty nice feature. I didn't know about it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Huh, didn't realise that Chrome had a comparable feature. Updated the answer

Comment: @Quentin  not just "comparable". Built-in and pretty great :-)

Comment: Perfect and very clear instructions. Well earned +1, thank you.

Comment: This is not working for me (Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)) I check the element has `style="display: none;"` completely removed, (so even the style attribute was removed), so maybe it only works when the attribute change? Not if the attribute is removed? **Solution**: I right-clicked on the parent element and selected Break on Subtree change instead